# FlutterFragment with FlutterPlugin - how to get a reference

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm currently using a FlutterFragment inside an AppCompatActivity.

Also, I'm using a pre-warmed up flutter engine and a FlutterPlugin to have a methodChannel from and to native/flutter when needed.

I am currently in a situation where I want to start a specific method to flutter via the plugin when my FlutterFragment is loaded.

I know right now that `onAttachedToEngine` is called in the FlutterPlugin when the plugin is attached to Engine.

But now the FlutterFragment needs to call the plugin when it starts.

How can I make sure the plugin is attached to the engine before the FlutterFragment invokes the plugin call. And the other way around, how can I make sure the FlutterFragment is attached and ready before the plugin calls anything on the fragment.

The only thing I have seen is the `ActivityAware` interface. I thought of getting the fragment from the fragmentManager from the activity, but these interface methods are never called for some reason.

Side-note: I can't change the AppCompatActivity to a FlutterFragmentActivity that easily, so if it's not needed, then that has my preference.